# can still see imageview even when invisible during rotation

Tags: java, android, imageview, rotateanimation

I don't understand why this is happening.  I set imageview so that it is invisible.  Then rotate it. However I can see the imageview flicker on and off the screen. How come setvisibility isn't working immediately?

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mystuff);
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            animation = new RotateAnimation(0, 0,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);


            animation.setDuration(0);
            img.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: why not `View.GONE` ?

Comment: would it change anything?  Isn't the difference just whether one takes up layout space or not?

Answer (score 0):

when you rotate the device, the view is recreated. so the onCreate is called again and your img is recreated. Maybe that's your problem. Otherwise show where this code stands in.